# How to disallow audio spatialization for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I'm working on an App that creates an immersive audio experience using mono points sources (`AVAudio3DMixingSourceMode.pointSource`) connected to an `AVAudioEnvironmentNode`.

I use `AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithm.HRTFHQ` for the sources and a `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo` channel layout for the environment output to generate a head-tracked, binaural audio stream when using compatible headphones (Apple AirPods Pro/Max).  For the head-tracking, I use the `CMHeadphoneMotionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()` callback.

It works pretty well and generates a convincing 360º immersion.

However, if I register the App with the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`, iOS automatically offers the user to spatialize my *Stereo* output in Control Center, which leads to an undesired double-spatialization.

Is there a way to disallow spatialization for my App?

Based on the comment in the API [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avsamplebufferaudiorenderer/3750310-allowedaudiospatializationformat) for `AVPlayerItem`, I changed the output format to `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Binaural` with the hope that this would disable spatialization but it still shows up as *Stereo* in the spatialization UI.